# Ubuntu 14.04 AMD/Intel Hybrid Switchable Graphics NOT WORKING

Tags: 14.04, ati, intel-graphics, hybrid-graphics, switchable-graphics

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on the HP 4530s with AMD Radeon HD 6490M/Intel HD Graphics 3000 Switchable graphics.

I have installed the first Intel driver from [here](https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main/pool/main/i/intel-linux-graphics-installer/intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.6-0intel1_amd64.deb).

Then I reboot so far there are no problems

Then I install the ati driver "amd-catalyst-14-4-rev2-linux-x86-x86-64-may6.zip" and reboot.

The system is opening low graphic mode. I also tried switch integrated Intel graphics card everything works fine. Any ideas what to do to fix this problem?